# Ubuntu 23.04 MySQL set root password from non-interactive .sh script in docker

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

I have a docker ubuntu image used for automated testing that needs several things installed, one of those being a mysql server. I install it using apt.
I can't use the server because I don't have the root password. Normally I can set it interactively with the mysql client, but how can I do this non-interactively from a bash script? I just want to set the password to "123", it doesn't need to be secure, this is just for automated testing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
mysql -u user -p123
```

Comment: I did a fresh install of mysql-server and when I try mysql -u user -p123 I get:
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)